# How to get json_decode working for a long, but validated (JSONLINT) json string?

Tags: php, json, php-8

I went to jsonlint and this json string reports as valid:

```
-stackoverflow- truncated, length is over 153,515 characters, see below
```

It seems to have a few nested json subobjects.  It also has some internal single quotes

On Windows 10, from the CLI, running PHP

```
$ php -v
PHP 8.0.1 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2021 23:43:39) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

You can directly run the code to see the error as follows:

```
$raw = file_get_contents("http://md5.mshaffer.com/WSU_STATS419/stackoverflow/json_decode/error.json");
$try = json_decode($raw, true);
var_dump($try);
exit;
```

Here is a link to a pretty form of the json, validated by jsonlint

```
http://md5.mshaffer.com/WSU_STATS419/stackoverflow/json_decode/jsonlint.json
```

Here is a link to a base64_encoded form

```
http://md5.mshaffer.com/WSU_STATS419/stackoverflow/json_decode/error.b64
```

Comment: Ends up with NULL in Ubuntu 20.10 as well. Maybe it is even not valid? Need to verify.

Comment: I couldn't paste the jsonlint URL (too many characters), but it returns valid.  And it was generated on a function webpage.  Too bad jsonlint doesn't have some bitly like notation for longer examples.

Comment: I am wondering how it tells being valid, when the URL is not valid because of its length.

Comment: Looks like `$raw = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($raw));` might do the trick before `json_decode`

Comment: @mshaffer Please, do **not** use utf8_encode. It is not, despite it's name, some kind of "fix all my UTF-8 problems" function. It simply converts from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 - which if you have iconv available, can be more clearly written as  `iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $raw)`. Running it on a string which is not, in fact, in ISO-8859-1 encoding, will give you "valid" but completely nonsensical UTF-8.

Comment: @NigelRen Please do not recommend that code. The iconv half of it does nothing, because the utf8_encode half of it has already mangled the string into something that is valid UTF-8, but almost certainly not the intended text. If you see any code using utf8_encode or utf8_decode, there is an extremely high chance that it is completely broken, because those functions are misused far more often than they are properly understood.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm voting to close this question as "needs debugging details", because it's not at all clear what string you've passed to what JSONlint implementation, and what error you're getting when you run the given PHP code.

Comment: Close if you would like.  I can't give a direct minimal example because stackoverflow limited the characters.  I posted the string on the web, with auxiliary files.  It's up to you.

Comment: @IMSoP, I merely did what anyone can do - recommended what appeared to be a solution which had a reasonable amount of votes and no comments stating it had flaws.

Comment: @NigelRen Absolutely understandable, and I am not criticising you for being fooled as dozens have over the years. I just want to make sure you know for future reference that it is horribly broken. If you want to confirm my assessment for yourself, read [the manual page for utf8_encode](https://php.net/utf8_encode).

Answer (score 1):

The JSON of your link is not valid because it contains non `UTF-8` characters.

I would recommend you to add the flag `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR` (PHP >= 7.3) to `json_decode`, or to test the output of `json_last_error`, just so you know what's happening.

```
$raw = file_get_contents("http://md5.mshaffer.com/WSU_STATS419/stackoverflow/json_decode/error.json");
$try = json_decode($raw, true);
var_dump(json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_UTF8);
# bool(true)
```

You can add the `JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE` (PHP >= 7.2) to strip the offending characters:

```
$try = json_decode($raw, true, 512, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE);
var_dump($try);
# array(40) { ["maxLevel"]=> ...
```

But it's hardly something that you want to do, unless in desperation.

---

Investigating a little, the offending characters are the `é` of `Denucé`, the `ç` of `Curaçao` and the `ä` of `Städel`. Your string feels like `ISO-8859-1`:

```
var_dump(mb_check_encoding($raw,'UTF-8'));
# bool(false)
var_dump(mb_check_encoding($raw,'ISO-8859-1'));
# bool(true)
```

> As [@IMSoP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157957/imsop) pointed out, `mb_check_encoding` can't differentiate between `ISO-8859-1`, `Windows 1252`, `ISO-8859-1` or any single-byte encoding.

The following work-around will correctly convert this **specific string** to `UTF-8` before parsing the JSON:

```
$raw = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $raw);
$try = json_decode($raw, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
var_dump($try);
# array(40) { ["maxLevel"]=> ...
```

BUT, please fix the JSON generation that's done upstream, to make it valid `UTF-8`, seriously.

**Side-Note**: As `mb_detect_encoding` doesn't check the whole string, it is unreliable. It will "say" that your string is `UTF-8`, which is not the case here.

Comment: Note that mb_check_encoding will not return false for any single-byte encoding, because any string of bytes is technically valid in ISO-8859-1, however unlikely as a "natural" string. It's therefore possible this is actually a related encoding - Windows 1252 is extremely common, and in some contexts ISO-8859-15. A key character added to both, in different positions, being the Euro symbol, which didn't exist when ISO-8859-1 was invented, but is rather important to much of Europe now!

Comment: @IMSoP My bad, you're right. Dealing with those single-byte encodings is almost impossible programmatically.